# LAN traffic brings down Internet connectivity

Tags: networking, router, lan

My "work" network is organized like this:

Internet connectivity is through a consumer wireless router, which only has 100mbit LAN ports. A server is plugged into one LAN port of the router, and a gigabit switch is plugged into another LAN port. Several people's computers, as well as another wireless router acting as access point, are plugged into the switch.

Seemingly randomly, everyone would lose Internet access from time to time. Eventually it was discovered that the outage happened whenever a colleague `scp`-ed large amounts of data between their own computer and the server. During these outages, accessing websites on the Internet, accessing the management page of the router, and pings to the router all result in timeouts.

What are some likely reasons why traffic inside the LAN breaks Internet? What are some potential ways to investigate further? Are there any potential solutions?

(I am open to all kinds of responses, from rigorous solutions to wild hacks, since it seems that the problem might not be solved "properly". To provide some context, the boss has rejected several times requests to get a better router, or to even purchase a switch; the gigabit switch everyone relies on right now is my personal property. He does get quite pissed whenever Internet broke, however.)

Comment: If the PCs talk directly to the server, why is it on a 100Mb segment when all the PCs are on a 100/1000Mb?? You'll get FAR better performance if you move the server to the gigabit switch. You'll also likely reduce strain on the router device since it won't need to handle any traffic between PCs and server since it'll all get handled in layer 2 on the gigabit switch.

Comment: @MaQleod Because the server is in another room. In fact, the main router, the server, and the gigabit switch + its connected devices are in 3 separate rooms, and there are all kinds of random reasons why nothing can be moved. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That’s unfortunate. Any chance you can run a cable through the ceiling to connect the server to the switch?

Comment: @MaQleod Nope. We're using existing cables in the wall already, no more cables can be pulled, and the rooms are actually quite far apart. Really, my first reaction to the problem is "why are we using this PoC router???" and asked for either a better router or a gigabit switch right next to the existing router, so at least the LAN can be all gigabit. But see remark about the boss above. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: In that case, the best suggestion I can offer is to buy a better router. You should have a business class router to handle business class traffic, not a dinky home router (I get the boss has said no, but in all honesty, I don't think you're going to find any real way to get around the fact that it is the bottleneck and the sole source of the problem). I would also suggest a more efficient data transfer protocol (SMB or NFS are going to be far more efficient than SCP).